connecting and reading from AMQ using jpype hangs some times
We are using JPype to connect to an AMQ broker and read the queue. The program works fine. However, it is frequently getting hung in the connection state. Below is the program we are using. Can someone assist us to troubleshoot the issue? We have investigated and the firewall is working fine.
import jpype
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def consume_message(queue_name):
    try:
        print("Start the JVM")
        if not jpype.isJVMStarted():
            jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath())

        print("Set SSL properties")
        ssl_options = {
            "java.naming.security.protocol": "ssl",
            "javax.net.ssl.keyStore": args.keystore,
            "javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword": args.keystore_pwd,
            "javax.net.ssl.trustStore": args.truststore,
            "javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword": args.truststore_pwd
        }

        print("Create a connection factory")
        connectionFactory = jpype.JClass("org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory")()
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(args.broker_url)

        print("Set SSL options")
        for key, value in ssl_options.items():
            jpype.java.lang.System.setProperty(key, value)

        print("Create a connection")
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection()
        print("client_id")
        print(args.client_id)
        # connection.setClientID(args.client_id)
        connection.setDefaultClientID('queue' + str(datetime.now()))

        print("start")
        connection.start()

        print("Create session")
        session = connection.createSession(False, jpype.JInt(1))

        print("Lookup queue")
        queue = session.createQueue(queue_name)

        print("Create consumer")
        consumer = session.createConsumer(queue)

        print("Hello connecting to AMQ and started receiving messages.......................")
        print("Start receiving messages and wait until end time")
        end_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=args.end_time)

        while datetime.now() <= end_time:
            message = consumer.receiveNoWait()
            if message:
                # print(message)
                parse_message(message.getText())
                time.sleep(args.sleep_time)

        print("Done waiting......")

    except jpype.JException as e:
        print(f"JPype Exception: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An Error Occurred: {e}")
        return "An error occurred: " + str(e)
    finally:
        # Close connections and shutdown JVM
        if connection:
            connection.close()
        if jpype.isJVMStarted():
            jpype.shutdownJVM()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not jpype.isJVMStarted():
        jpype.startJVM(
            jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(),
            "-Djava.class.path=" + "/mtproject/activemq-all-5.10.2.jar",
            "-Djava.util.logging.config.file=" + "/mtproject/logging.properties"
        )
    
    print("start amq client...")
    queue_name = args.queue_name
    consume_message(queue_name)
    print("end amq client...")
    jpype.shutdownJVM()

We're using the following versions:

Jpype 1.3.0
AMQ 7.10.3.CR2-redhat-00001
Python 3.6.8


JPYPE VERSION:  1.3.0

AMQ : 7.10.3.CR2-redhat-00001

python version : 3.6.8

Out of curiosity, if you're using Red Hat AMQ why wouldn't you work directly with Red Hat to investigate the issue?

Can you be more specific about what is getting "hung" exactly? Do you see any error messages? How does your application behave? Please clarify. Thanks!

the program occasionally hungs. then i use ctrl +c and open a new terminal and execute the program again. even then sometimes it will work and sometimes don't. not able to determine where the issue is

Where does it hang exactly? You need to clarify the problem more or your question is likely to be closed.

connection = connectionFactory.createConnection() in this step

Do you have a thread dump which demonstrates where in createConnection() the thread is hanging?
